# How to use the backend, actions and reducers of a react app in a react-native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, expo-yarn-workspaces

I have a react app with its server, actions and reducers all in a single directory. I also have the screens of a react-native app in another directory. How can I hook up the actions and reducers of the react app to work with the react-native app? 
In general, what's the best way to co-develop react and react-native apps?

My workspace structure is as follows:

```
root
    server
    client
        common
        web
        native
```

I followed the following steps:

create package.json in client directory, with the following:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "web",
    "native",
    "common"
  ]
}
```

and in common I created the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Then in the client directory, I ran yarn install, and changed all import references to the directories which are now in `common` to `common/dirName` instead of the relative path `../dirName` I had before. But I get `common/dirName` could not be resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use yarn workspaces and separate all commonly needed methods in another folder, then import that common folder as a package in each project

Comment: I have made a common folder with all the common files and folders. How do I exactly use yarn workspaces to import these files into each project?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, check out my edit

Answer (score 0):

You need package "common" as dependency for web and native packages. Add to package.json (web / native):

```
"dependencies": {
    "common": "0.0.1"
}
```